# Why does sizeof(MACRO) give an output of 4 bytes when MACRO does not hold any memory location?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Below is the small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 'A'

int main()
{
    char a;
    printf("max[%d] sizeof[max][%ld]\n", max, sizeof(max));
    a = max;
    printf("a[%d] sizeof[a][%ld]\n", a, sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

And the output of the program is:

```
max[65] sizeof[max][4]
a[65] sizeof[a][1]
```

Can anyone help me to understand why the sizeof(max) is 4 bytes?

Comment: Remember that macros are _text replacements_ that happen _before_ compilation. So the compiler sees `sizeof('A')`, which is a meaningful expression.

Comment: As `sizeof()` returns a value of type `size_t`, best to use a matching print specifier like `"%zu"` rather than `"%ld"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sizeof(max)` is replaced by the preprocessor with `sizeof('A')`. `sizeof('A')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, and the latter is 4 on your platform.

For the avoidance of doubt, `'A'` is an `int` *constant* in C, **not** a `char`. (Note that in C++ `'A'` is a `char` *literal*, and `sizeof(char)` is fixed at 1 by the standard.)

Comment: For additional avoidance of doubt, `sizeof(char)==1` _by definition_ in both C and C++, and IIRC the official name of the token `'A'` is "character literal" in both languages, as well.  But the _type_ of the expression `'A'` is `int` in C and `char` in C++.

Comment: @zwol in C it is *character constant*. The word "literal" is only used in the C Standard for "string literal" and "compound literal".